# UITextField clear when selected, but also restore data if nothing is input

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a table with UITextFields, and I want to make it so that when a textfield is selected, the current info is cleared (to allow new input), but if the user decides (after selecting) that they don't want to change it, I want them to be able to click elsewhere and the data from before reappears in the textfield.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good way to do this that's nice and user friendly is to use the `placeholder` property. Set up your viewController as the textfield's delegate (as described by Andeh) then add the following code:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    textField.placeholder = textField.text;
    textField.text = @"";
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField.text.length == 0) {
        textField.text = textField.placeholder;
    }
    textField.placeholder = @"";
}
```

And you're done. If you have multiple `UITextField`s on the page and you don't want this behaviour for all of them you can add a check to the methods above.

Answer (score 2):

In the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` delegate method, save the current value to a persisting variable before clearing the UITextField. Then in the `didFinishEditing` delegate method, if the new length of the user input is 0 set the text back to the stored value!

[UITextField Delegate docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextFieldDelegate) for reference.

Answer (score 2):

First I think you have two sets of behaviors here.

1. The text field must clear the value when you begin editing. This exists: `-clearsOnBeginEditing`.
2. The text field must restore the previous text if text is empty. Subclassing seems the better solution.

Here is a possible sample class:

```
// MyRestoringTextField.h
@interface MyRestoringTextField : UITextField
@end

// MyTextField.m
@interface MyRestoringTextField ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *previousText;
@end

@implementation MyRestoringTextField
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    BOOL result = [super becomeFirstResponder];
    self.previousText = self.text;
    return result;
}
- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder
{
    BOOL result = [super resignFirstResponder];
    if (self.text.length == 0)
        self.text = self.previousText;
    return result;
}
@end
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To clear and then restore a textField if you fail to make an entry, use the following delegates as such:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:textField.text forKey:kTextFieldIdentifier];
    textField.text = @"";
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@""])
        textField.text  = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                    stringForKey:kTextFieldIdentifier];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of `iOS 8.1`, `textFieldDidBeginEditing` is already receiving a cleared text. You should use

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

to initialized the placeholder field.