# UINavigationController issue

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In my app I'm switching between `UIViewController` using Navigation Controller and the Action Segue "Show". But for example if I write something in a `UITextView` and I return in that `UIViewController` the text is deleted. How I can keep the information ? Like in the `UITabBarController`.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17756677/2990958
hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the easiest way

Comment: for an easier solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12169660/2990958.

Answer (score 0):

You can create uiviewcontroller objects in app delegate and use that objects for swapping between view controllers.  In current scenario, whenever you load same view controller again, it is created as fresh object so UITextView is initialized again, so text you entered will not be saved.

Or you can save value of UITextView in global variable or NSUserDefaults on viewwilldisappear() and initialize again in viewwillappear()

Answer (score 0):

U can use restoration ID in the IB for that particular UITextView.

[image]